# Summary of gender

Tags: r, summary

I am running a summary of my data and when I do summary(sn$Gender)
I get:

Length: 202 (I have 202 responses)
Class: Character
Mode: Character

It should say female 99 and male 103.
Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Use the `table` function i.e. `table(sn$Gender)`  or convert it to `factor` and use the `summary` i.e. `summary(factor(sn$Gender))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is based on the `methods` for `summary` and which method is getting called.

```
methods('summary')
#[1] summary.aov                    summary.aovlist*               summary.aspell*               
#[4] summary.check_packages_in_dir* summary.connection             summary.data.frame            
#[7] summary.Date                   summary.default                summary.ecdf*                 
#[10] summary.factor                 summary.glm                    summary.infl*                 
#[13] summary.lm                     summary.loess*                 summary.manova                
#[16] summary.matrix                 summary.mlm*                   summary.nls*                  
#[19] summary.packageStatus*         summary.PDF_Dictionary*        summary.PDF_Stream*           
#[22] summary.POSIXct                summary.POSIXlt                summary.ppr*                  
#[25] summary.prcomp*                summary.princomp*              summary.proc_time             
#[28] summary.srcfile                summary.srcref                 summary.stepfun               
#[31] summary.stl*                   summary.table                  summary.tukeysmooth*
```

Usually on a `factor` class, `summary.factor` is called, but if it is `character`, it calls the `summary.default` and based on the conditions in `summary.default`

```
 if (is.factor(object)) 
    return(summary.factor(object, ...))
 .
 .
 .

 else if (is.recursive(object) && !is.language(object) && 
       (n <- length(object))) {
     sumry <- array("", c(n, 3L), list(names(object), c("Length", 
         "Class", "Mode")))
 .
 .

  else c(Length = length(object), Class = class(object), Mode = mode(object))
 .
 .
```

it returns the 'Length', 'Class', and 'Mode'.

One option is to either convert the column specifically to `factor` and then use the `summary` or call `summary.factor`

```
class(sn$Gender)
#[1] "character"

summary(sn$Gender)
#Length     Class      Mode 
#  202 character character 


summary.factor(sn$Gender)
# female   male 
#   93    109
```

---

But, we can avoid this confusion and use `table(sn$Gender)`

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
sn <- data.frame(Gender = sample(c('male', 'female'), 202, 
                      replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```